# Setting Background Color of JPanel

Tags: java, swing

So I've tried using getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white),
and tried setting the table and scrollpane to white as well.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BalanceFrame extends JFrame {

private JTable table;
public BalanceFrame(String title, String value) throws Exception {
    super(title);
    SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
    getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, scrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, scrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, scrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, getContentPane());
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, scrollPane, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, getContentPane());
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    ResultSet res = Operations.writeBalanceResult(value);
    JTable table = new JTable(Operations.writeResult(res)); 
    table.setAutoResizeMode( table.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);




    for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
        int preferredWidth = tableColumn.getMinWidth();
        int maxWidth = tableColumn.getMaxWidth();

        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            Component c = table.prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
            int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + table.getIntercellSpacing().width;
            preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, width);

            if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth) {
                preferredWidth = maxWidth;
                break;
            }
        }

        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = tableColumn.getHeaderRenderer();

        if (headerRenderer == null) {
            headerRenderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }

        Object headerValue = tableColumn.getHeaderValue();
        Component headerComp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, headerValue, false, false, 0, column);
        preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, headerComp.getPreferredSize().width);

        if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth) {
            preferredWidth = maxWidth;
            break;
        }

        tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(preferredWidth + 6);
    }



}
}
```

This is the only frame I can't get to change color, it's created here in another class -

```
menuItemBalanceSheet.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            balanceFrame = new BalanceFrame("BalanceSheet", value);

                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        balanceFrame.setSize(1200, 600);
                        balanceFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        balanceFrame.setVisible(true);  
                    }
                });
```

I've gotten another panel to successfully change color by doing this

```
companyPanel = new CompanyPanel();
companyPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
```

Comment: Is it the balanceFrame you are trying to change?

Comment: For better help sooner post a [mcve]. Not sure why your post got so many upvotes

Comment: The scroll pane is blocking the content pane, components, generally, aren't transparent

Comment: In your case, you may need to change the color of the table and/or cell renderer depending on what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting the background of the scroll pane's [*viewport*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html) by using `scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.XXX)`.

Comment: Just beware, if you set a non transparent component as the viewPort's view, it will obscure the viewport and you want see the change ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
balanceFrame.getContentPane().setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

OR

```
balanceFrame.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: No luck with that :\

Comment: Have you tried setting your panel to opaque like this: panel.setOpaque(false) @Zack